# ResultSet Query

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee

```
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement(); //1
Statement stmt2=conn.createStatement(); //2 
ResultSet resultSet1=stmt.executeQuery("-----"); //3 

while(resultSet1.next()) { //4
    ResultSet resultSet2 = stmt.executeQuery("-----");  //5
}
```

Will Line Number 5 cause any changes in `resultSet1` (declared in line 3 )....As per my observation, `resultSet1` had been changed after the execution on line 5.

Please explain whether my observation is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Statement javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.